# Javascript traversal and how retrieve parent tree based on parent attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a menu. I'd like to get the tree of any given selected item.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Deserts</a>
        <ul class="category">
             <li data-parent="Deserts">
                 <a>Cakes</a>
                 <ul class="sub-category">
                     <li data-parent="Cakes">
                         <a>Fruit</a>
                         <ul class="sub-category">
                             <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Jelly</a>
                             </li>
                              <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Puree</a>
                             </li>
                              <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Concentrate</a>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                 </ui>
             </li>
        </ui>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So if a user clicked on `Jelly`. It would return something like:
`Cakes/Fruit/Jelly`.

How can I retrieve the tree of the clicked element? Is `.parentsUntil()` appropriate here?

```
$("a").click(function () {
    alert($(this).parentsUntil('.category').data('parent'));
});
```

Comment: Note, `</ui>` should be `</ul>`

Comment: @guest271314 ah thanks dude!

Comment: Why would `"Jelly"` be last item in expected result? Are you trying to get `.textContent` of the previous and current  elements?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. Since Jelly was the item selected. I'm just trying to get it's parents into one big string

Comment: Consider updating Question to clarify that you want to get the `.textContent` of previous `data-parent` elements, not the `data-*` attribute value.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm confused. What's the difference? data-parent holds the text value.

Comment: No element at `html` at Question has a `data-parent` attribute where the value is set to `"Jelly"`.

Comment: @Modelesq: If your HTML doesn't have to keep this particular structure, I just added a suggestion for how you might retrieve `['Cakes', 'Fruit', 'Jelly']` rather than just `['Cakes', 'Fruit']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. `data('parent')` only returns the first attribute, though, so you need to use `jQuery#map` (as well as filter the parents so that only `li` are included).

The demo below shows how you can get an array of all categories to which a given item belongs. This doesn't include the item itself (e.g. "Jelly"), but I will add some suggestions below as to how to remedy that issue.

(Also, as someone pointed out in the comments above, you should be using `</ul>` tags rather than `</ui>`.)

```js
$("a").click(function () {
    var categories = $(this).parentsUntil('.category', 'li').map(function (i, e) {
        return e.getAttribute('data-parent')
    }).toArray().reverse()
    console.log(categories.join('/'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Deserts</a>
        <ul class="category">
             <li data-parent="Deserts">
                 <a>Cakes</a>
                 <ul class="sub-category">
                     <li data-parent="Cakes">
                         <a>Fruit</a>
                         <ul class="sub-category">
                             <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Jelly</a>
                             </li>
                              <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Puree</a>
                             </li>
                              <li data-parent="Fruit">
                                 <a>Concentrate</a>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**If you don't mind changing your HTML**, and you want to include the item name itself along with the names of the enclosing categories, here are my suggestions:

Instead of using `data-parent` and having to reference the same information on each category item (like `data-parent="fruit"`), you should define a `data-name` attribute that exists on `li` regardless of whether they represent an item or a category. Your top `ul`, which holds *every* category and sub-category, could be labeled as `.categories` to distinguish it from other `ul`. I think code will speak better than words here, so I've included an example implementation. Take a look at how the HTML is restructured and how it makes the jQuery code a little easier.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    var names = $(this).parentsUntil('.categories', 'li').map(function(i, e) {
        return e.getAttribute('data-name')
    }).toArray().reverse()
    console.log(names.join('/'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories">
  <li class="category" data-name="Deserts">
    <a>Deserts</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="category" data-name="Cakes">
        <a>Cakes</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="category" data-name="Fruit">
            <a>Fruit</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="item" data-name="Jelly">
                <a>Jelly</a>
              </li>
              <li class="item" data-name="Puree">
                <a>Puree</a>
              </li>
              <li class="item" data-name="Concentrate">
                <a>Concentrate</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great. Makes alot more sense for the structure to look like this. For some reason it's not grabbing the selected item's text. But that's ok; I can figure that you. Thank you again!

Comment: What text is missing? `data-name` is applied on every item and category as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's just on my local machine. Somethings weird :P

Comment: Did the snippet itself work incorrectly or did the error occur after you applied those edits yourself? Maybe try copying the posted code again if it was the latter.